# restar el resultado de dos subconsultas MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo 3 tablas en mi base de datos que son cuentas, ingresos, gastos. Me gustaría tener la suma de ingresos y gastos dada una cuenta específica, y luego obtener la diferencia de estas sumas. Este es un ejemplo resumido de la estructura de las tablas:

```
+--------------+
|   accounts   |
|--------------|
| id           |
| name         |
+--------------+

+--------------+
|   income     |
|--------------|
| id           |
| amount       |
| account_id   |
+--------------+

+--------------+
|   expense    |
|--------------|
| id           |
| amount       |
| account_id   |
+--------------+
```

Y esta es mi consulta actual:

```
select (t1.amount - t2.amount) as subtraction
from accounts a
inner join (
  select account_id, COALESCE(sum(amount), 0) as amount
  from income 
  where account_id = 4
) t1 on a.id = t1.account_id
inner join (
  select account_id, COALESCE(sum(amount), 0) as amount
  from expense 
  where account_id = 4
) t2 on a.id = t2.account_id
```

esto funciona solo cuando tengo registros en ambas tablas, muchas veces solo tendré movimientos de ingresos y me gustaría obtener ese resultado, entonces como debo estructurar mi consulta?

Answer (score 1):

Una forma es sumando un `union` de ambas consultas:

```
select t.account_id, 
       sum(t.amount) as amount
       from (   
        select  account_id, 
                sum(amount) as amount
                from income 
                where account_id = 4
                group by account_id

        union all

        select account_id, 
               sum(amount*-1) as amount
               from expense
               where account_id = 4
               group by account_id
    ) t
```

Básicamente son tus dos consultas "unidas" mediante un `union all` (no sirve el `union` común en este caso) y el truco es considerar los gastos en negativo: `sum(amount*-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Podrías:

- Crear una sub-consulta para obtener el total de `incomes` y `expenses` para cada `account`.
- Utilizar [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) para el caso en que alguno de estos sea `null` (*no tiene registros*)
- Finalmente podrías restar el total de ambos resultados.

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT
  IFNULL((
    SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM income AS i
    WHERE i.account_id = a.id
  ), 0) AS incomes,
  IFNULL((
    SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM expense AS e
    WHERE e.account_id = a.id
  ), 0) AS expenses,
  ((SELECT incomes) - (SELECT expenses)) AS balance
FROM accounts AS a
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1de93/3)</kbd>

#### Observaciones:

- Si necesitas obtener estos resultados solo para la cuenta `4`, solo necesitas agregar `WHERE a.id = 4`
- Si no necesitas saber el total `incomes` y `expenses`, entonces podrías directamente [restar ambas sub-consultas](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1de93/4).

Answer (score 0):

Si en tu consulta en el segundo join puede que no hayan datos, puedes cambiar el inner join por left join, y para evitar que t2.amoun sea null usas ifnull(t2.amount,0)):

```
select (t1.amount - ifnull(t2.amount,0)) as subtraction
from accounts a
inner join (
  select account_id, COALESCE(sum(amount), 0) as amount
  from income 
  where account_id = 4
) t1 on a.id = t1.account_id
left join (
  select account_id, COALESCE(sum(amount), 0) as amount
  from expense 
  where account_id = 4
) t2 on a.id = t2.account_id
```

Comment: ya lo intente e hice pruebas y me devuelve null

Comment: @FeRcHo actualize mi respuesta, ahora ya te va a funcionar